# how can I check page edited and confim leave page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want implement a method like facebook , when there is edited data in page confirm that he/she want exit page without save them,

I found below code to get confirm,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Are you sure you wanna leave without saving edited data?";
}
```

I know I should write a code that check data change by client side (js(jquery)), my first idea is check input element changes something like below code

```
var edited=false;
$('input ,select').change(function(){
 edited=true;
});

 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(edited)
    return "Are you sure you wanna leave without saving edited data?";
}
```

what is the full method of checking edit occur in page and confirm user to leave if there was change in page.

Comment: What else do you think you'd need?

Comment: it depends, you can check the W3C/MDN for complete list of standard input controls, but what about custom ones? like moving items across lists? One way could be use certain class or data attributes to mark the editable stuff in your page, and then use those to select what to monitor for change events.

Answer (score 0):

my idea was correct and work correctly,
I write it here to help others in future

```
(function($){
var edited=false;
$('input ,select').change(function(){
 edited=true;
    });

 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(edited)
    return "Are you sure you wanna leave without saving edited data?";
}  

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could implement the check directly on the controller, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" onChange="var edited = true"> </input>
```

then, when this code's going to be executed:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){

    if(edited)
        return "Are you sure you wanna leave without saving edited data?";

}
```

if the inputbox has changed, it will find edited variable set to true and it will ask to the user if he/she's sure to leave the page, without saving the data.

Comment: I have too item in  my page, I cant do this one by one?